# How can I verify my program on calculating form-factor is correct?

Tags: graphics, 3d

Can you give me some date set or sample input/ouput?

I am learning the Radiosity. Though I can render a image to see if it "looks" correct, I find it necessary to do a diff with another program's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at web sites that explain Radiosity and copy example from there or [use a free Radiosity tool to generate some images](http://dudka.cz/rrv).